# Identify link before certain text in Selenium IDE

Tags: css-selectors, selenium-ide

I am trying to click on an image that is before the text and I can't seem to work out my precedents and descendants. My main problem is that the first link (image) is always selected. I'd appreciate some help.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="jqTlAl">

<a class="tlAdd" href="/tablelink/add?foo">
<img src="/icn/a.png" title="Add links"></a>
<span>add Files</span>
</div>

<div class="jqTlAl">
<a class="tlAdd" href="/tablelink/add?bar">
<img src="/icn/a.png" title="Add links"></a>
<span>add People by Role</span>

</div>
```

Here is what I have attempted so far:

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//div/div/span[contains(., 'add People by Role')]/preceding::a/img[@src='/icn/a.png']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

and

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//span[descendant::span[contains(.,'add People by Role')]]//img[@src='/icn/a.png']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give a try with the below xpath:

//span[contains(text(),'add People by Role')]/preceeding-sibling::img

Comment: Hi @Ramki, Yes that is what worked! Here is what I used in the end:

`//span/a[contains(., '${Option}')]/preceding::img[@src='/icn/cog.png'] [1]`